# passenger_max_pool_size is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I set passenger_max_pool_size to 30 in my nginx.conf file, however, in number of occasions, passenger spawned more than 30 processes, it ranges from 30 to 90 processes.  if max is 30 it should not have more than 30 processes, I am confused.  Any tips will be great. Thanks!

here is my nginx.conf settings below

```
http {
    passenger_log_level 1;
    passenger_debug_log_file /var/log/nginx/passenger.log;
    passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;

    passenger_max_pool_size 30;
    passenger_pool_idle_time 90;
    passenger_min_instances 20;
    passenger_max_requests 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to determine the number of passenger processes? are you using passenger-status? We have an apache based setup and we have the passenger_max_pool_size directive in a conf file and it has never failed.